# #Error in SQL while updating table using join

Tags: mysql

I got an error while updating the table with the join query. The error message is:

> Error Code: 1064. You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'from employee details join employeedept on employee details.emp_dept=employeedept.' at line 3

Can anyone help me to resolve this error?

```
update employeeDetails
set employeeDetails.emp_age = employeeDetails.emp_age+20, employeeDetails.emp_salary = employeeDetails.emp_salary-500
from employeeDetails
join employeedept on employeeDetails.emp_dept = employeedept.dept_name 
where employeedept.dept_name = 'CSE';
select * from employeeDetails;
```

- List item

Comment: MySQL <> SQL Server - please correct you tags.

Comment: review Multiple-table syntax: https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/update.html

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried using MySQL's UPDATE JOIN syntax yet? e.g.:

```sql
update employeeDetails
join employeeDept on employeeDetails.emp_dept = employeeDept.dept_name
set
  employeeDetails.emp_age = employeeDetails.emp_age+20,
  employeeDetails.emp_salary = employeeDetails.emp_salary-500
where employeeDept.dept_name = 'CSE';

select * from employeeDetails;
```